# Create dynamic SQL query to list all users from over all databases

Tags: sql, dynamic

I want to create a dynamic query to list all unique users in a single table, from which I only need the username, from all different databases, which have the same database schema.
As the names of the tables differ on the different environments I would like to have something dynamic so it can be executed on different environments.
The basic query looks like this:

```
SELECT USERNAME FROM DATABASE.DBO.USERTABLE WHERE LOGIN = 'Y'
```

To execute this query on 3 databases, it would look like this:

```
SELECT *        
FROM   ( SELECT UT.USERNAME AS 'DB1'
        FROM   DB1.DBO.USERTABLE UT          
        WHERE  UT.LOGIN = 'Y'       
        ) a      
full outer join         
        ( SELECT UT.USERNAME AS 'DB2'      
        FROM   DOSSIER.DBO.USERTABLE UT   
        WHERE  UT.LOGIN = 'Y'    
        ) b ON a.DB1 = b.DB2         
full outer join         
        ( SELECT UT.USERNAME AS 'DB3'      
        FROM   DB3.DBO.USERTABLE UT   
        WHERE  UT.LOGIN = 'Y'    
        ) c ON a.DB1 = c.DB3
ORDER BY A.DB1
```

Is there an easy way to create a dynamic query for this, which can be applied on multiple databases?

I've already tried the code below, but I found it hard to get the JOIN ON working.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

SELECT  @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + ' AS '+ name + ' FULL OUTER JOIN ON' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' ) + 'SELECT USERNAME AS ' + name + ' FROM [' + name + '].[DBO].[USERTABLE] AS '+ name
FROM    master.sys.databases
WHERE   NOT [name] IN ( 'master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

PRINT @Sql;
```

So what I would like to create is the thing below.

SELECT USERNAME
FROM [DATA].[DBO].[USERTABLE]

RESULTS

USER1

USER2

USER3

SELECT USERNAME
FROM [OTHER].[DBO].[USERTABLE]

RESULTS

USER3

USER4

USER6

SELECT USERNAME
FROM [NEW].[DBO].[USERTABLE]

RESULTS

USER1

USER6

USER7

SELECT USERNAME
FROM [SOME].[DBO].[USERTABLE]

RESULTS

USER2

USER5

USER7

So the resulting query should present the list below.

DATA____OTHER___NEW_____SOME____

USER1___________USER1___________

USER2___________________USER2___

USER3___USER3___________________

________USER4___________________

________________________USER5___

________USER6___USER6___________

________________USER7___USER7___

As mentioned, this has te be dynamic, as:
1. I don't know before how many databases are on an environment;
2. It has to be easy usable for anyone;

Comment: What about UNION ALL instead of outer join?

Comment: Hi jarlh, thank you for your suggestion. This however isn't what I'm looking for. I need 1 column from each database, joined on another column. The union all puts the data from all the columns in 1 column.